# Unit of retained heap in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, memory-management, memory-leaks, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I am getting numeric value of 1294736 in 'retained Heap' column when I use Memory Analyzer in Eclipse-Helios, what is the unit of this numeric value ? is it bytes or kBytes?

Same query for shallow heap value.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same question. It seems to be in bytes. You can confirm this by writing a simple java program that repeated add stuff to a list, then run it with "java -Xmx2m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" to max its heap usage to 2M, and dump the heap when it becomes full, then load the hprof file into the tool to verify.

Comment: I can verify that indeed it is in bytes based on my observations and analysis.